# Stop parsing datetime.datetime to datetime64[ns] for pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to set a pandas index with a datetime.datetime object. However, pandas always automatically parses this into its datetime64[ns] object while creating the index. As I later want to work with datetime.datetime object this is an issue as not all functions exist.

Minimal example

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
dates = [datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2), datetime(2021, 1, 3)]
df.index = dates
print(type(df.index[0]), type(dates[0]))
```

Output is

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I tried setting it also with pd.Index() while specifying a dtype, however pandas keeps parsing.

Comment: Hi, Paul! What index data type do you want?

Comment: Hi Giba, I would like datetime.datetime as index type.

Comment: Why would you want to use that type? Pandas has its own type for handling datetimes (pd.Timestamp), with dedicated functionality (methods; `dt` accessor for datetime Series for instance). Vanilla Python datetime objects would have to be handled as an object-type Series.

Comment: Simply because I am using some later functionality which is written for datetime objects and thus relies on its syntax and functions.

Comment: @Paul this seems like an "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/269241)", where you assume that the solution is to avoid Pandas datetime dtype, where in reality you mean to ask "can I do Y with Pandas"? For example, Pandas does have good support for timezones and DST, it uses Pytz and Dateutil internally: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-zone-handling. But without knowing your actual use case, it's impossible for anyone to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul, I mean that Pandas uses `datetime64[ns]` as its internal datetime representation for indexing because of performance. But, try to use this as well:

```
...
    df.index = dates
    index_as_datetime = df.index.to_pydatetime()
...

print(type(index_as_datetime[0]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html

Comment: Thanks you. I stubbled across that earlier as well. I am just always very hesitant switching between different timestamp module to not mess up timezone, daylight saving etc. and would have loved staying with a datetime.datetime as index. If I understand correctly hat is not possible though